# Better way of doing React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a lot of state in my component therefore I'm suspecting I'm doing something wrong.

I have a registration component that requires the user to fill in first name, email and so on. When the user hits next and the form is valid I use React-Router to transition to next registration phase. Here is my problem. I transition to for example /account/delivery where account is the module and delivery the section to be filled in. There can be many sections in one module and there can be many modules. In the JavaScript I have.

```
{  
   "modules": [  
      {  
         "module": "account",
         "section": [  
            {  
               "uri": "delivery",
               "id": 783743847834
            },
            {  
               "uri": "invoice",
               "id": 9304830948
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "module": "someother"
      }
   ]
}
```

In `getInitialState(...)` I have fetched the correct module and the correct section for the user to fill in data. I do this by reading the `this.props.params` and the modules and sections are there through props when the initial page is loaded. Now I need to get all the fields for a section. There can be 4-30 different fields that need to be fetched from the database. A dropdown can have up to 300 selections. I was thinking of getting them in `componentDidMount(...)` but then all the fields would be React state.

All fields are dynamically created by the admins in the backend and will be different for every module and section.

Do you have any suggestions how this can be designed in a better way? Essentially this is what I'm doing:

- A user loads a page
- The header of the request is read to determine the host and to fetch the correct client from database that matches the host.
- The modules and sections are read that are related to the client. The client have modules that can hold sections.
- React-Router then loads the relevant component, modules and sections are passed to the component using props

Comment: It seems like you're trying to do a lot of stuff, which is relatively separate, inside just one, or very few, components.  I find one of the tricks to react is producing many simpler components instead of fewer complex components.  It's tempting early on to produce extremely complex root level components instead of splitting tasks between smaller children and simply feeding data back to the root.

Comment: Well you are right. I have a lot of subcomponents under the root and passes props to those. But still, there is a lot of state.